# File split command using AWK with header on each file

Tags: awk

```
awk -F "\",\"" 'NR==1 { hdr=$0; next } $10 != prev { prev=text=$10; gsub(/[^[:alnum:]_]/,"",text); $0 = hdr "\n" $0 } { print > ("test."text".batch.csv") }' test.batch1.csv
```

There is awk command which isn't working well which splits the files(based on $10 column value from the file) and put the header on each file.
I tried to understand the command line but I didn't understand quite well. 
Appreciate if anyone would explain to me what each line is doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
awk -F "\",\"" '                      # set field separator to ","
NR==1 {                               # pick the header from the first record
    hdr=$0; next                      # and skip to next record
}
$10 != prev {                         # if 10th the field differs from previous
    prev=text=$10                     # prev and text are set equal to 10th field
    gsub(/[^[:alnum:]_]/,"",text)     # remove all but aA-zZ, 0-9, _ from text
    $0 = hdr "\n" $0                  # header preceeds data
}
{                                     # f.ex. ..,"foo/bar_123",... would output
    print > ("test."text".batch.csv") # to file test.foobar_123.batch.csv
}
' test.batch1.csv                     # input file
```

If it's not working as it used to, I'd check first that the data file is sorted on the 10th field.

Comment: that's right James, its not working as expected. it is creating a mess in data. Thank you very much for your suggestion and help.

Answer (score 0):

since you didn't provide an input sample, here is a simplified version.

assume you want to split the file on the key value

```
$ cat file
header
1
2
2
3
3
3

$ awk 'NR==1{header=$0; next}              # save header
    prev!=$1{fn=$1;                        # when value changed, set new file counter,
             prev=$1;                      # save current key value,
             $0=header RS $0}              # and insert header before first record
            {print > FILENAME"."fn}' file  # print records to the file

$ head file.{1..3}
==> file.1 <==
header
1

==> file.2 <==
header
2
2

==> file.3 <==
header
3
3
3
```